# in Angular 8 HttpClient request inside a Promise fails and the promise will never resolve

Tags: javascript, angular, tags, observable, angular-promise

I'm using ng-select package with Angular 8 to add tags to the messages. I need to create new tags on user request. This is the documentation example:

```
addTagPromise(name) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.loading = true;
        // Simulate backend call.
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ id: 5, name: name, valid: true });
            this.loading = false;
        }, 1000);
    })
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/tags-backend-example.component.html

This code adds a new tag after one second and it works. But I need a real server side request.
The problem is that when I add a HttpClient request, anything, it does not execute at all!

For example in this code the 'get' request will never execute and the Promise will never resolve!:

```
addTagPromise(name) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get("http://google.com").subscribe(); <--- Will never executed
      this.loading = true;
      // Simulate backend call.
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ id: 5, name: name, valid: true }); <--- Never resolves
        this.loading = false;
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxb5r6?file=src%2Ftags-backend-example.component.ts

And my final code is something like this:

```
addTag(title: string) {
  const newLabel: CategorySet = { type: 'message', title };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.categoryService.add(newLabel).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.code === 1) {
        // If added, get the list og gategories again
        this.getCategoryList();
        resolve();
      } else {
        this.toastr.error(res.message);
        reject();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping Observable into Promise? You can use `toPromise` operator form RxJs. `this.categoryService.add(newLabel).toPromise()`

Comment: @dev Then where should I write the subscribe body? Can you rewrite the last code snipper using toPromise?